# How to select from multiple tables with no matching columns

Tags: mysql

I want to query between three tables that have no matching columns .I have used `UNION` but it replace `idDisplayNetwork` and `idDevice`  with `idCountryin` the result.

```
SELECT idcountry, 
       name 
FROM   country 
UNION 
SELECT iddevice, 
       name 
FROM   device 
UNION 
SELECT name, 
       iddisplaynetwork 
FROM   displaynetwork
```

I want this kind of output

```
   { idCountry: '18ec1e07-9c89-4d2c-aefe-a7bd8966fab4',
    Name: 'Russia' },
   { idCountry: '31ceda51-9ce8-4380-bd41-c95f660e2ad4',
    Name: 'Turkey' },
   { idDevice: 'c0180c24-2df5-4082-b050-94dfaf1d5174',
    Name: 'Desktop and Laptops' },
  { idDisplayNetwork: '771434a0-0e6d-4206-90f5-f6abf85690d1',
    Name: 'search network' },
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i really surprise that you haven't check your own question after posting as , in title jquery and below is mysql .

Comment: Can you at least post sample data and desired output of your query?

Comment: i have updated my question and mention the output that i want @peterm

Comment: You can't do that with any relational database. All rows of a result must have the same columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those IDs are the same, you should rename your output columns in the query similar to this:

```
SELECT idcountry AS ID, 
       name 
FROM   country 
UNION 
SELECT iddevice AS ID, 
       name 
FROM   device 
UNION 
SELECT 
       iddisplaynetwork AS ID,
       name 
FROM   displaynetwork
```

---

The result that you just posted is impossible to have, but instead you can do something like this:

```
SELECT idcountry AS ID, 
           name,
           'Country' AS Type
    FROM   country 
    UNION 
    SELECT iddevice AS ID, 
           name,
           'Device' AS Type
    FROM   device 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
           iddisplaynetwork AS ID,
           name,
           'Display Network' AS Type
    FROM   displaynetwork
```

The output will be like this:

```
{ ID: '18ec1e07-9c89-4d2c-aefe-a7bd8966fab4',
    Name: 'Russia', type: 'Country' },
   { ID: '31ceda51-9ce8-4380-bd41-c95f660e2ad4',
    Name: 'Turkey', type: 'Country' },
   { ID: 'c0180c24-2df5-4082-b050-94dfaf1d5174',
    Name: 'Desktop and Laptops', type: 'Device' },
  { ID: '771434a0-0e6d-4206-90f5-f6abf85690d1',
    Name: 'search network', type: 'Display Network' },
```

Comment: You have it backward, it should be `'Country' as type`.

Answer (score 0):

**[UNION statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/union.html)** need to share the same columns to work.
As specified the first statements' column names are taken for the other result sets.

Comment: then what will be the way to write this query @Seven Schneider

Comment: You need to explain better what kind of result you're trying to get. Add sample data and expected results to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make any sense to append resultsets to each other if they don't share the same columns (kind of data). It's a semantic error, nothing MySQL related.

If you want to connect each table instead of appending the results, use `JOIN` statement then.
This assumes all tables share at least 1 key for referential integrity.

Example

```
SELECT n.*, d.*, c.* FROM displaynetwork n
JOIN device d
ON n.name = d.name
JOIN country c
ON n.name = c.name
```

**Update:**

Try `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

**Update:**

Having 2 tables, colors and names, with names(name,randomNumber) and colors(id,color), the following statement is exactly your output:

```
SELECT id, color FROM colors
UNION ALL
select randomNumber, name FROM names
```

So for me, it doesnt have to be the same alias or name of a column. But im using MariaDB, don't know if this behaves different.